# Strange output with static objects

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I can't understand what's happening...

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
// main.cpp

#include "some_header.h"

void bar();

int main()
{
  foo();
  bar();
}

// file.cpp

#include "some_header.h"

void bar()
{
  foo();
}

// some_header.h

#include "foo.h"

inline
void foo()
{
  static Foo instance;
}

// foo.h

#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::Foo() \n"; }
  ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo() \n"; }
};
```

**Output**

> Foo::Foo()
>
> Foo::~Foo()

The question is: why there's no second "Foo::Foo()" in the output? I think that it should be here because each translation unit (in my case main.cpp and file.cpp) should have its own Foo object (because of static keyword). Am I wrong? Can somebody quote the standard, please?

If i move the definition of Foo object from the function like this

```
// some_header.h

#include "foo.h"

static Foo instance;

inline
void foo()
{

}
```

the output will be

> Foo::Foo()
>
> Foo::Foo()
>
> Foo::~Foo()
>
> Foo::~Foo()

Is it inline magic or am I missing smth more fundamental?

What I need to do - I need to add boost::mutex object in some function for my header-only library to synchronize some WinAPI function calls like this:

```
inline
void some_func()
{
  static boost::mutex sync;
  boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(sync);
  // Call some WinAPI function
}
```

How can I do it?

MSVC-11.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static` is a heavily overloaded keyword in C++. At namespace scope, it means "entity has internal linkage, so every translation unit will have its own copy." At function scope, it means "there is only one such entity for the function and it persists across function calls."

So in your case, the funcion `foo()` simply has one object `Foo instance` with local scope, but global lifetime.

As for your mutex question, I can't see anything wrong with doing just what you posted in the question. `some_func()` will have a single instance of the mutex, and all calls to `some_fucn()` will share that one instance (and since C++11, it will be correctly and thread-safely initialised by the first such call). I'd say that's exactly what you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And there will be only one boost::mutex object across all translation units which include and use this function, right?

Comment: @FrozenHeart Yes, there will be just one object. `C++11[dcl.fct.spec]§4`: "An `inline` function with external linkage shall have the same address in all translation units. A `static` local variable in an `extern inline` function always refers to the same object."